# Can't use "draggable" inside an Angular Dashboard Framework Widget

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, dashboard

I'm trying to use an draggable element inside an adf-widget, but it seems that `draggable="true"` is ignored inside adf-widgets.

i've tried the simplest way with, to test if draggable="true" is working:

```
<div style="background-color: #000000; width: 50px; height 50px;" draggable="true">...</div>
```

but it wont become draggable. Is there an other way to get an element draggable?

Comment: Are you using any library for drag and drop?

Comment: not at the moment. i've found out, that the element becomes draggable using javascript like: ´document.getElementById('id').setAttribute('draggable', true);´ ... i don't understand why draggable="true" is not working...

Comment: i think adf is overwriting the draggable attribute. if i look at the browsers codeinspector the draggable attribute isnt set false or true.. after setting it with javascript it is true.. is there a way to force "true" and make it not overwriteable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that ADF-Wigets are overwriting "draggable attributes". I resolved this issue using ngMouseenter and javascript like:

```
<div class="draggable-element" ng-repeat="item in itemlist" id="{{item.id}} ng-mouseenter="setDraggable(item.id)>{{item.name}}</div>
```

And inside my controller:

```
$scope.setDraggable = function(id){
   document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('draggable', true);
};
```